# В textArea остаётся \n после отправки сообщения, JavaFX

Tags: javafx, textarea

Добрый день! Зашёл в тупик, прошу помочь.
Поле ввода сообщения textArea2, при нажатии Enter текст отправляется на сервер.
Проблема в том, что в textArea2 курсор стоит на второй строке после отправки сообщения. Не помогают ни .clear(), ни .setText("").

```
textArea2.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)  {
                    onSendMsg();

                }
            }
        });

public void onSendMsg() {
        try {
            out.writeUTF(textArea2.getText());
            if (textArea2.getText().equals("/end")) {
                socket.close();
            }
            textArea2.clear();
            textArea2.deleteText(0,textArea2.getText().length());
            textArea2.requestFocus();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забавная ситуация. Перемещение каретки не даёт результата, т.к. \n всё равно остаётся в поле и хоть пишешь с первой строки отправляется на сервер на 1 пустую строку больше.
Вставил textArea2.clear() позже, в методе который выполняется после onSendMsg(), тогда поле стало очищаться. Т.е. сообщение уходит на сервер, сервер делает Броадкаст рассылку и после этого срабатывает textArea2.clear().
Так понимаю, \n из Stream приходит уже после того как выполнится onSendMsg(), поэтому в этом методе нет смысла очищать поле.